# where can i find advanced backbone.js examples

Tags: backbone.js

Can someone please direct me to a resource containing an advanced backbone.js example?
by advance I mean multiple pages with nested views, complex layouts etc.

I have browsed the web, gitHub repository, blogs and even purchased the "recipes with backbone" book. All of the samples are at a level of simple SPA (yes I know backbone is for that, but I know it can do much more) level, a todo list calendar, adding and deleting notes etc.
Is there something a bit more advanced and complex that I can learn from? I'm no expert in backbone
 but for me the best way is to learn by sample

Comment: Even now in 2014 there's nothing vague, ambiguous, or incomplete about this question. Anyone's who has started out learning about backbone has been frustrated by the simplicity of the common backbone examples which omit a lot of important features of the language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### DocumentCloud

http://www.documentcloud.org/public/search/ and perhaps https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch in particular

#### Tzigla

http://tzigla.com/ source here http://tzigla.com/assets/board.js

#### QuietWrite

http://www.quietwrite.com/ source here http://www.quietwrite.com/assets/app.js

#### Diaspora X^2

https://github.com/bnolan/diaspora-x2 with source in Coffee

#### InterMine Lists Client

Peek into the source, it is packaged by Brunch and it is a learning experience for me too:

https://github.com/radekstepan/intermine-lists-client

Answer (score 17):

While it's not a complete example (it doesn't do any server-side communication, yet), I've been building a larger example app at http://bbclonemail.heroku.com

This project serves two purposes for me: providing a more in-depth example app, and providing a playground for new ideas that I have which often end up in my Backbone.Marionette add-on (go to http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette).

There are also several good examples listed in my http://backbonetraining.net/resources page, including a Wine Cellar application, a backbone 'store', and a handful of sample projects on github from various people.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Backbone.Marionette; been looking for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my github,  I've started to build out a framework to help people use backbone and Jquery to build mobile development projects. But you can use the same ideas, with Node.js and Express. Really any Javascript project.

https://github.com/DarrenHurst/BroadStreet

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the todo-example? Is it complicated enough?

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples-todos

Comment: i doubt this is enough, since he mentiones a todo list or a calendar as easy level applications in his original post.
i bet he would love a todo application online, where people can share todo lists, and all that :P that would be a proper complex layout and structure. but that's unexistant. at this very moment that is :P

Comment: Yes i read this samples, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting sample app organised in modules containing models, collections and views.

demo: http://githubviewer.org/

sources: http://github.com/tbranyen/github-viewer

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get inspired with this [Backbone Contact Manager](http://srackham.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/routeless-backbone-contacts-2-0/) and I found it interesting the way it manages the views, only by model an collection events.

The article also has some tips at the end.