# An Introduction to Backbone that isn't a To-Do App?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, frameworks

I've been searching for an app with some pragmatic value to use as an introduction Backbone. However, I have only been able to find dozens of small To-Do Apps of limited scope.

If anyone could recommend an introduction to Backbone with a broader scope, that **is not** a To-Do App, I would appreciate it immensely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick google search brought me the following https://www.google.co.za/search?q=backbone+advanced&oq=backbone+advanced&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7219j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8 and our very own has some pretty good answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195179/where-can-i-find-advanced-backbone-js-examples

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/BackboneCRUD